# How can I create a shortcut that acts as a tally

Tags: bash, shortcut-keys, shortcuts

For my work I have to do repetitive tasks with weekly deadlines. I like to know how close I am to finishing these tasks so I tend to keep a tally on a piece of paper. Unfortunately I travel a lot and don't always have a pen or a notebook. This is fine because I just gedit as an alternative, but sometimes I forget to save gedit when I shutdown and lose track of my tally.

What I really want though is a way of setting a shortcut so that each time I complete a task it is logged somewhere and saved instantly. It also needs to be quickly and easily displayed somehow.

Comment: What would this shortcut do? A shortcut to what? Where are the tasks stored? What kind of tasks are they? Please [edit] your question and describe what you need more clearly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way of solving that I found was to create a dash script that stores the tally in a text file and displays the value using `notify-send`.

I used `source` to set the location for the values I wanted to keep a tally of:

```
#!/bin/sh
. /home/jesse/.scripts/tally
```

And the tally file just has a single line which reads:

```
written=0
```

Then I created functions for **show**ing the tally, **clear**ing the tally and **add**ing to the tally.

To show the tally I needed to start by reloading the tally to make sure it is up to date. Then I can use `notify-send` like this:

```
show() {
  . /home/jesse/.scripts/tally
  notify-send -i "/home/jesse/.scripts/icon.png" \
  "Total for this week:" "Written: $written"
}
```

To **add** to the tally the function needs to read from the tally, add 1 to the value, rewrite the tally and then call the show function:

```
add() {
  num=$(($written + 1))
  printf "written=$num" > /home/jesse/.scripts/tally
  show
}
```

The clear function is fairly self-explanatory:

```
clear() {
  printf "written=0" > /home/jesse/.scripts/tally
  show
}
```

Finally, in order to call the individual functions from the script I needed to finish the script with `$@` so that the arguments can be called verbatim. The complete script is:

```
#!/bin/sh
. /home/jesse/.scripts/tally
show() {
  . /home/jesse/.scripts/tally
  notify-send -i "/home/jesse/.scripts/icon.png" \
  "Total for this week:" "Written: $written"
}
add() {
  num=$(($written + 1))
  printf "written=$num" > /home/jesse/.scripts/tally
  show
}
clear() {
  printf "written=0" > /home/jesse/.scripts/tally
  show
}
$@
```

From there I could assign keyboard shortcuts to call individual functions from the script and manage a good looking tally that is displayed in the notification window just by pressing a couple of buttons.

Hope this helps somebody. This is my first dash script and I'm happy with it, but there's bound to be cleaner ways of achieving this.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use emacs with org-mode. It's much more powerful than just simple manage your tasks, but might be worth to dig into.